# Bootstrap typeahead dropdown list overflow issue in case long text

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, autocomplete, typeahead, autosuggest, dropdown

I am using bootstrap-typeahead as an autocomplete option in my project. Everything is working fine, but if the options are larger than the size of the input box, then the option's text are overflowing from the dropdown area.[See the Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PDKky.png)

Please suggest something.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe share some of your code! Maybe position absolute with width 100% is working but can't say that for sure.